# fontawesome stacking on primeng button

Tags: css, font-awesome, primeng

I have tried different ways to add stacked icons on a primeng pbutton with text but no avail.  Anyone have a solution for this without the button being twice its normal height?

I've tried:

```
<button pButton type="button" icon="fa fa-stack fa-download fa-ban fa-stack-1x" iconPos="left" label="no download"></button>
```

and

```
        <button pButton type="button">
            <span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-download fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-1x" style="color:tomato"></i></span> no download
        </button>
```

But both are not giving the results i want.

edit to explain in pictures.

I want it like this [image: Desired button result]
but i'm getting this [image: Button actual result]

Answer (score -1):

Try with a `aria-hidden="true"` on the `<i>` element. Just like it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
<button pButton class="btn btn-default" type="button">
  <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```